# getClass() can not work the same as .class

Tags: java, class

If I have a enum class:

```
enum WorkDays {
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY;
}
```

And I have:

```
WorkDays day1 = WorkDays.valueOf("MONDAY");
```

for the method:
`public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf​(Class<T> enumType, String name)`

If I force to check the enumType, I can write:

```
WorkDays day2 = Enum.valueOf(WorkDays.class,"TUESDAY");
```

But it can't be:

```
WorkDays day2b = Enum.valueOf(day1.getClass(), "MONDAY");
```

Most people say that `Object.class` should be called by a class, but `getClass()` should be called by an Instance, but it seems that the difference is more than just this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getClass` returns a `Class<? extends WorkDays>` but `Enum.valueOf` expects its first argument to be a `Class<WorkDays>`.

To get the correct class type, i.e. `Class<WorkDays>`, you can use [the `getDeclaringClass` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#getDeclaringClass--):

```
WorkDays day2b = Enum.valueOf(day1.getDeclaringClass(), "MONDAY");
```

Now it happens that `day1` *is* a `Workdays`, so you could also cast to the correct type:

```
WorkDays day2b = Enum.valueOf((Class<WorkDays>) day1.getClass(), "MONDAY");
```

Note that this cast will fail if `MONDAY` has a body (for example if it overrides a method of the enum).

Comment: What is the difference between getClass and getDeclaringClass again?

Comment: That would also be my question, i.e. could someone explain "The value returned by this method may differ from the one returned by the Object.getClass() method for enum constants with constant-specific class bodies."?

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 Noticed you can redefine methods declared in the enum class, for some specific enum values? That's implemented by the enum value defining its own class, that extends the enum class. Therefore, for such an enum value, getClass() actually gives its own class, which is a subclass of the declaring enum class.

Comment: @DorianGray For example if the enum contains a `public String m() { return name(); }` and `MONDAY` is declared as: `MONDAY { public String m() { return "NOT MONDAY!";} }, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, ...`, then the class of `MONDAY` will be an inner class of `WorkDays`.

Comment: Thanks! No wonder there is a `getDeclaringClass`, this is basically to solve the inner class problem,

Comment: But if I call `day1.getDeclaringClass() == day1.getClass()` it actually return `true`, so but still you are saying that the return of different class is causing the issue I have?

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 In your case they return the same thing at runtime. Your error is at compile time because the return type of `getClass` does not match the argument type of `valueOf`.

Comment: @assylias Thanks. I always forget that the error can be in compile time or runtime. Coming from using a dynamic language like python....